# Назначение интерфейса org.springframework.web.HttpRequestHandler

Tags: java, spring, servlet

В Web приложении работают в связке следующие инструменты: Hibernate, Spring Context, Spring ORM, Servlet API.

Вопрос: почему когда пишешь сервлет обязательно нужно реализовывать интерфейс `HttpRequestHandler` вместо простого `HttpServlet`? Неужели это лишь для того, чтоб было возможным инжектить бины?

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете Spring MVC, тогда все ваши запросы попадают в DispatcherServlet.

Сюда попадают все запросы:

- `protected void doDispatch(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception`

метод doDispatch вызывает getHandlerAdapter. Происходит итерация по `List<HandlerAdapters>`, обратите внимание на **ha.supports(handler)**:

- ```
  protected HandlerAdapter getHandlerAdapter(Object handler) throws ServletException {
  if (this.handlerAdapters != null) {
      for (HandlerAdapter ha : this.handlerAdapters) {
          if (logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
              logger.trace("Testing handler adapter [" + ha + "]");
          }
          if (ha.supports(handler)) {
              return ha;
          }
      }
  }
  throw new ServletException("No adapter for handler [" + handler +
          "]: The DispatcherServlet configuration needs to include a HandlerAdapter that supports this handler");
  }
  ```

Реализация **HandlerAdapter** для **HttpRequestHandler**:

- ```
  public class HttpRequestHandlerAdapter implements HandlerAdapter {

  @Override
  public boolean supports(Object handler) {
      return (handler instanceof HttpRequestHandler);
  }

  @Override
  @Nullable
  public ModelAndView handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
          throws Exception {

      ((HttpRequestHandler) handler).handleRequest(request, response);
      return null;
  }

  @Override
  public long getLastModified(HttpServletRequest request, Object handler) {
      if (handler instanceof LastModified) {
          return ((LastModified) handler).getLastModified(request);
      }
      return -1L;
  }}
  ```